# Rollback a committed transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way to `rollback` a committed transaction in `oracle 11g`

I have made a `delete from table` in db and committed it, now I want to `rollback` the committed change. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: There is no rollback **after** committing. It is either rollback **or** commit.

Comment: there is some concept of flash back, but i am unable to use it....

Comment: You are not aware of the concept or you dont have rights for flashback?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot rollback what has already been commited. What you can do, in this particular situation, as one of the quickest options, is to issue a flashback query against a table you've deleted row(s) from and insert them back. Here is a simple example:

**Note**: Success of this operation depends on the value(default 900 seconds) of `undo_retention` parameter - period of time(can be reduced automatically) during which undo information is retained in undo tablespace.

```
/* our test table */
create table test_tb(
   col number
);
/* populate test table with some sample data */
insert into test_tb(col)
   select level
     from dual
  connect by level <= 2;

select * from test_tb;

COL
----------
         1
         2
/* delete everything from the test table */    
delete from test_tb;

select * from test_tb;

no rows selected
```

Insert deleted rows back:

```
/* flashback query to see contents of the test table 
  as of specific point in time in the past */ 
select *                                   /* specify past time */
  from test_tb as of timestamp timestamp '2013-11-08 10:54:00'

COL
----------
         1
         2
/* insert deleted rows */
insert into test_tb
   select *                                 /* specify past time */  
    from test_tb as of timestamp timestamp '2013-11-08 10:54:00'
   minus
   select *
     from test_tb


 select *
   from test_tb;

  COL
  ----------
          1
          2
```

Comment: Didnt get what is this solution? Will i be able to recover my data?

Comment: @Varun - If the data is still present in your `UNDO` tablespace, yes.

Comment: For more info about flashback you can visit http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm

Comment: Another method is to use FLASHBACK TABLE - which sounds similar but is quite different: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS OF TIMESTAMP 
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2003-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

then insert to the delete table as

```
INSERT  INTO  employee (SELECT * FROM employee AS OF TIMESTAMP 
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2003-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'));
```