# How can I reset the oracle JDBC?

Tags: sql, oracle, jakarta-ee

I started to learn Java a month ago.
Today I was studying some SQL phrases which are necessary for creating websites using JSP and Servlets.

I used SQL Developer and JDBC.
After doing some insert/delete/update manipulation, I accidentally clicked on 'commit' instead of 'roll back'.
So some of my data in certain tables are lost and so am I...

I think I must delete and re-install JDBC to have all the basic data that Oracle offers.
But I'd like to ask for some help here before doing that, if there is any simpler way.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you in advance.
I am not sure if it will help but here is the SQL I used:

---

```
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS VALUES(280, 'DataAnalytics', null, 1700);

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS (DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, MANAGER_ID,
LOCATION_ID) VALUES(280, 'DataAnalytics', null, 1700); 

UPDATE emps SET SALARY=30000WHEREEMPLOYEE_ID=101; 

UPDATE EMPS SET (JOB_ID, SALARY, MANAGER_ID)= (SELECT JOB_ID, SALARY,
MANAGER_ID FROM EMPS WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=108) WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=109; 

DELETE FROM EMPS WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=108; DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE
EMPLOYEE_ID=103;
```

Comment: There is no need to re-install anything.  jdbc has nothing to do with your commit. you cannot undo a commit.  If your database is configured for oracle flashback, then see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853150/rollback-a-committed-transaction

Comment: JDBC provides connectivity between your Java runtime environment and the Oracle database, so reinstalling it will not affect any data. Is your sample data provided from some script? It doesn't look like a [standard Oracle test schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/comsc/introduction-to-sample-schemas.html).

Comment: Also it's worth being aware that you don't need to write SQL or Java in uppercase. For historical reasons there is something of a tradition of uppercasing language elements in SQL, as there used to be for HTML and CSS in the early days, although personally I think it's unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was confusing some concepts. My data is from Oracle, but I created some tables (like emps which is a copy table of 'Employees') to do some tests without ruining the original oracle's DB. The probleme is I did the same manipulations with original tables by mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing `JDBC` with `SQL`. `JDBC` is short for Java Database Connectivity, and it's a Java standard used to connect from Java to relational databases (See Oracle's documentation on JDBC here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/introducing-JDBC.html#GUID-864DB502-5E50-4044-8132-33D6AAF8927A). Depending on what version of the `Oracle Database` you're running, the `JDBC` driver version, and which client you're using, you may find that you are missing some functionality, but that functionality is probably completely separate from the SQL you ran.

When you use `SQL Developer` to connect, you may be using a `JDBC` connection, but in all likelihood, you are using either a Basic or TNS Connection Type. Those do not rely on JDBC. The SQL you ran from `SQL Developer` modified the data because that's what SQL is used for. SQL is short for Structured Query Language, and it's widely used to manage data in relational databases.

By using `SQL Developer`, you should have access to all of the standard functionality that Oracle has to offer. You may be missing some features, but that is completely normal if you or your organization does not have a licensing agreement with Oracle and have not configured those features. Reinstalling `JDBC` won't change that.

What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to restore your data, `JDBC` has nothing to do with that. You will have to either: 1. `Flashback` the database or table (depending on which version of Oracle you're running,) which will restore the database (or the relevant object(s)) back to a specific point in time before you executed those SQL commands. 2. Use `OEM` or `RMAN` to restore the database to a time before you executed those SQL commands, or 3. Delete the relevant data and re-create (or re-import) your data.

Since you `committed` the transaction to manipulate that data, these are likely going to be your only options to restore the database how it was. If you know the original values that belong in those tables, I suppose that you could also write up more SQL to change the values back to the original. This may result in your desired outcome, but be forewarned that this method (and option #3) would not be considered a restore, and all of the changes that you made up to that point would still be apart of the transaction history. If that doesn't matter, that may be the easiest route for you to pursue.

Comment: Thanks!! I actually was confusing some concepts. So I am using oracle database version 11, and while testing some manipulations I accidentally committed. So the data was changed for good. And I'd like to restore the original oracle database, to a time before those manipulations. I will look up some information to try your first and second proposition. Thanks very much. Hope i can help somebody in the future...

Comment: Happy I could be of assistance. If I'm not mistaken, 11g does not support flashback at the table level, so I think your best options are probably going to be: 1. Flashback the database (assuming archiving is enabled) or 2. Do a restore using RMAN. Good luck, and keep researching!